# Take in cell as argument, and change its value

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks for taking the time to take a look at my question. I don't use VBA much but need to use it in this case. I'm trying to have a function take in a cell, perform an operation if the cell has a certain value, and change it back to the original value after waiting a bit. This is the approach I've taken so far, the operation I want to run works, but the cell value doesn't change. Thanks

```
Public Function Send_Alert(ByRef Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = 1 Then
        Target.Value = 0 'change cell's value to 0

        'operation here works, but left out for simplicity

        'I want the function to wait for a specified time before changing the target cell's value back
        newHour = Hour(Now())
        newMinute = Minute(Now())
        newSecond = Second(Now()) + 20
        waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
        Application.Wait waitTime
        
        Target.Value = 1 'change cells value back to 1
        
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: A user defined function that is called from a worksheet by itself cannot change the value of any cell but the one that calls the function.

Comment: If your seconds are 40+ and you add 20 and keep the minutes the same when this runs you are setting the time in the past. Use F8 to step through and see if the cell changes to 0